# Prove $(n-2)!+(n-1)!+n!=(n-2)!n^2$ for $n\ge 2$.

Tags: factorial

Sorry I'm not sure how do the symbols such as the same as or powers. This is probably a very easy question but I can only think of proving it by proof of exhaustion. However as $n$ is basically infinite above $2$ I don't think this is right.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hint:$$n!=n(n-1)!=n(n-1)(n-2)!$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a factor from $(n-2)!$ likes the following:
$$(n-2)! + (n-1)! + n! = (n-2)!(1 + (n-1) + (n-1)\times n) = (n-2)!(1 + (n-1)\times(n+1)) =  (n-2)!(1 + n^2 - 1) = (n-2)! n^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that:
$$n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot(n-3)\ldots$$
So therefore:
$$n!=n\cdot (n-1)\cdot(n-2)!=(n^2-n)\cdot(n-2)!$$
and:
$$(n-1)!=(n-1)\cdot(n-2)!$$
Putting it all together:
$$n!+(n-1)!+(n-2)!=(n^2-n)\cdot(n-2)!+(n-1)\cdot(n-2)!+(n-2)!=(n^2-n+n-1+1)(n-2)!=n^2(n-2)!$$

Answer (score 0):

we have 
$$n!=n(n−1)!=n(n−1)(n−2)! = n^2(n−2)! -n(n−2)!$$
then,
$$ (n−2)!+(n−1)!+n! = (n−2)!+(n−1)(n−2)!+n^2(n−2)! -n(n−2)! = n^2(n−2)! +\underbrace{(n−2)!-n(n−2)!+(n−1)(n−2)!}_{0} =n^2(n−2)!  $$