# Factorials with large Exponents..

Tags: arithmetic, exponential-function, factorial

$$\frac{(100!-99!)^{100}-(99!-98!)^{100}}{(98!-97!)^{100}}$$

$$\frac{(99! 99)^{100}-(98! 98)^{100}}{(97! 97)^{100}}$$

i was able to solve only till. How to proceed after this ?

How to solve these type of questions quickly ? is there any easy method ? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473316/prove-n-2n-1n-n-2n2-for-n-ge-2

Comment: You want to cancel out the $97!$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes! Simply Beautiful art..I want to Simplify

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(100!-99!)^{100}-(99!-98!)^{100}}{(98!-97!)^{100}}=98^{100}\frac{(100\cdot99-99)^{100}-(99-1)^{100}}{(98-1)^{100}}=\left(\frac{98}{97}\right)^{100}(99^{200}-98^{100}).$$